# ActiveRecord where returns ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
u = User.where("name = ?", "mateusz").limit(1)
u.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

So I cant do smth like u.email and so on. 
.find does right, returns User object.
Is there any chance to get an User object from ActiveRecord::Relation object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call `first` or `last` on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object:

```
u = User.where("name = ?", "mateusz").first
```

Comment: thanks this helped a lot. question though, so where assumes you always get multiple rows with that right? that's why you need the first?

Comment: In all cases I try, where returns a relation.

Answer (score 3):

If you expect to only find one record, you could use [find_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by):

```
u = User.find_by(name: 'mateusz')
```